# Django: TypeError: 'branch__organisation' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have 3 models:

```
class Organisation(CommonInfo):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gems = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)
class Branch(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, related_name='branches')
    branch_details = models.OneToOneField('BranchDetails', related_name='branch')
class GemsBoughtHistory(CommonInfo):
    gems_bought = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,default='',blank=True)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, related_name='gems_in_branch')
```

I have organisation's instance, which I got by :

View:

```
organisation_id = self.kwargs['organisation_pk']
organisation = Organisation.objects.get(pk = organisation_id)
organisation_form = self.organisation_form(request.POST,instance=organisation)
if organisation_form.is_valid():
    org = organisation_form.save()
    gems =  org.gems
    gems_bought_history = GemsBoughtHistory.objects.create(gems_bought=gems,branch__organisation=organisation)
    //gems_bought_history = GemsBoughtHistory.objects.create(gems_bought=gems,branch__organisation=org)
```

Now, while creating GemsBoughtHistory row, I get this error. "Invalid keyword argument".
How shall I traverse from branch to organisation in GemsBoughtHistory model??
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When using .create() you can't set values that do not reside on the created model. So, first create (or get an existing one from the DB) for the wanted organisation, then assign that branch to GemsBoughtHistory in .create().

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I fetched the branch object and then saved it in GemsBoughtHistory model.